# Which field of science applies the log-normal sample median distribution?

Tags: median, lognormal-distribution, application, sampling-distribution

Which field of science applies the log-normal sample median distribution (i.e. the sample median distribution with samples from a log-normal parent)? I noticed that incubation periods are assumed log-normally distributed but its sample median distribution isn't really studied.

Comment: I am aware of applications in which a lognormal distribution is a reasonable empirical fit to existing data. One is earthquake magnitudes, but that may be due to inability reliably to detect and record many tiny seismic events, an inaccuracy that may explain the sparse _lower_ tail of lognormal. thus diverting attention from the median as a useful measure. // I am not aware of an application in which lognormal is the natural consequence of a compelling mathematical model. So I don't know a good answer to your question. Will follow answers with interest.

Comment: @BruceET: You don't count multiplicative CLT as a compelling model?

Comment: Thank you everyone. I am writing a paper on the log-normal sample median distribution. So I am looking for its applications to be discussed in the introduction section.